# Why does df.info() give the wrong heading?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, google-colaboratory

The data set I use is the SOF survey 2019: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey

When I read the `survey_results_public.csv` file as a Data Frame, and use `df.info()`, I get values for non-null in count and vice-versa. I use the version `1.0.3`. Is this a problem of Pandas?

[image]

Comment: @jezrael Please look at the `Non-Null` and `Count` headers

Answer (score 0):

Those are not separate columns `Non-Null` and `Count`, it is a single `Non-Null Count` column.